# WordPress ShortTag Custom Variable

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I like to have a whole website build in wordpress. All through the site there will be telephone number, address, some link here and there...

I like to be able to defin variable shorttag in the admin panel somewhere, and be able to insert it in the WYSIWYG like that :

```
you can contact us anytime [phone] or visit us here : [address]
```

so changing addres or number is a snap !

any idea, i got http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-configs/screenshots/ but need to insert in php not shorttag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [do_shortcode()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function to output the shortcode values using php. Assuming that

Example:

```
<? echo do_shortcode('[phone]'); ?>
```

Using your plugin is easy to define shortcodes that are outputting the content of a custom setting

```
function get_phone($atts, $content = null) {
 return get_config('phone-settings');
}
add_shortcode('phone', 'get_phone');
```

Assuming that in your plugins, you have defined a custom settings with the key `phone-settings`

Comment: creative solution... will look if it possible to implement easely... thanks a lot